# In R how can I select every nth column and every nth row within those columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large data set and I want to select every nth column and every nth row within that column.

In this example if I want every 2nd column and every 2nd row I would get 9 and 11 for the first and 6 and 8 for the second.

```
x <- data.frame("x1" = c(1:4), "y1" = c(8:11), "x2" = c(14:17), "y2" = c(5:8))
x
```

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
x[seq_len(nrow(x)) %% 2 == 0, seq_len(ncol(x)) %% 2 == 0]
#>   y1 y2
#> 2  9  6
#> 4 11  8
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use vector recycling :

```
n <- 2
inds <- c(rep(FALSE, n - 1), TRUE)
x[inds, inds]

#  y1 y2
#2  9  6
#4 11  8
```